# Building a class that behaves like Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I'm trying to build a class which behaves like `Nullable<T>`, specifically the way I can access the underlying value of `Nullable<T>` class without having to explicitly call `nullable.Value`.

In the following example lines `check1` & `check2` both work.

```
Nullable<DateTime> nullable = new DateTime();
bool check1 = nullable >= DateTime.Now; //Works
bool check2 = nullable.Value >= DateTime.Now; //Works
```

I built my own class `TrackedValue` which remembers if the value it wraps has been changed. I've based mine on `Nullable<T>` and built the implicit & explicit operators.

`Nullable<T>` definition

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    public Nullable(T value);

    public static explicit operator T(T? value);
    public static implicit operator T?(T value);

    ...
}
```

`TrackedValue<T>` definition

```
public class TrackedValue<T> : IChangeTracking
{
    ...

    T trackedValue;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.trackedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.trackedValue = value;
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator T(TrackedValue<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator TrackedValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return new TrackedValue<T>() { Value = value };
    }
}
```

So I was expecting the following to work, however `check3` will not compile because of:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TrackedValue<System.DateTime>' to 'System.DateTime'`

```
TrackedValue<DateTime> trackedValue = new DateTime();
bool check3 = trackedValue >= DateTime.Now; //Does not work
bool check4 = trackedValue.Value >= DateTime.Now; //Works
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line specifically doesn't work because it requires an `implicit` conversion but you have it marked as `explicit`.

```
public class TrackedValue<T> : IChangeTracking
{
    T trackedValue;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.trackedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.trackedValue = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(TrackedValue<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator TrackedValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return new TrackedValue<T>() { Value = value };
    }
}
```

But naturally, you want to mimic the `Nullable<T>` model. So why does `Nullable<T> <= T` work implicitly but not yours? I believe it comes from the C# compiler itself. Eric Lippert has an [*excellent* blog series](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/) on how Nullables are compiled/optimized.

From what I understand, the compiler itself alters the written code/IL to a different instruction set altogether. Eric's [third entry](http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/03/nullable-micro-optimization-part-three/) on the series starts to demonstrate this. This is because it handles special cases for nulls generally I believe.

I'm not sure if you can work around this, but perhaps the simplest way is to simply mark the one conversion operator there as `implicit` instead and hope it doesn't cause any major issues for you with regards to consistency between `TrackedValue<T>` and `Nullable<T>`.

EDIT: One of those items of inconsistency will be say how comparisons are made.

Consider your line `bool check3 = trackedValue >= DateTime.Now` in the case that `trackedValue` is `null`. For a `Nullable<DateTime>` it goes kind of like this (note that this is not *exactly* what it is, see Eric's series. This is just for communicating the concept):

```
check3 = trackedValue.HasValue ? trackedValue.Value >= DateTime.Now : false;
```

The compiler *avoids* even calling the conversion operator. Yours on the other hand would attempt to run your implicit conversion (assuming you switch it to implicit) which could result in a `NullReferenceException` which is frowned upon (implicit operators should *not* throw exceptions). The reason why `Nullable<T>` defines the conversion operator as `explicit` is because for those times that you do directly cast (e.g., `DateTime casted = (DateTime)myNullableDateTime;`) can throw an exception if the value is null.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was keen to not have to type `.Value` so altering the operator is fine. I'm not actually that fussed regarding the consistency between the types. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Re: NullReferenceException, I can live with that for now, the code isn't for general consumption. Additionally `trackedValue.Value = null` is a valid situation is my case.

Comment: @JamesWood You're welcome! I edited my post with a concrete example of the differences. Hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 1):

You declared your conversion operator explicit, so while `bool check3 = trackedValue >= DateTime.Now; //Does not work`, this should work:

```
bool check3 = (DateTime)trackedValue >= DateTime.Now;
```

The other course of action of course is to declare it implicit.

Answer (score 1):

change the operator `T` to implicit:

```
public static implicit operator T(TrackedValue<T> value)
{
    return value.Value;
}
```